# How can I know the manufacturer of the PFD (Primary Flight Display) of the current mainstream passenger aircraft?

Tags: boeing-737, airbus-a320, boeing-747, boeing-777, electronics

I'm developing a computer vision software based on the photos of these PFD (Primary Flight Display). How can I know the manufacturer of these PFD of the current mainstream passenger aircraft: B737. B747, B777, A320, A330, A340?

I have tried to Google and to find documents about these aircraft, for example, I know the device reference of the PFD of B737 is G1000 made by Garmin, but for others, it's really difficult to find out the device reference of their PFD.

Here is an example of the PFD of B737.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[The 737 does NOT use a G1000...](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/AML-SA01818WI_1710.pdf) Many of these devices are made [by companies](http://www.b737.org.uk/flightinsts.htm) like [honeywell](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/en) or the [makers of the airframe themselves](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/passenger-aircraft/cockpits.html) although they may very well source the physical screen from another manufacturer.

Comment: Really thanks sir, from the document you provided, does 737 use the G5 EIS of Garmin? Or 737 is not on the list, so that means it does not use a G1000?

Comment: I am confused because the list only showed those who installed G5 EIS of Garmin, but 737 is not on the list. I don't know how you know that 737 does not use a G1000 from this list. Can you explain a little bit for me? Really thx!

Comment: @StoneSHI the G1000 is not certified for use with the 737 airframe (does not appear on the list) and thus would not be legal to install one (as per the FAA, other jurisdictions may have different rules but most are fairly in line)

Comment: The original A300-A320 system was by Aerospatiale, which was part of the Airbus Industrie consortium. Through a series of spin-offs and acquisitions, it became part of an independent supplier, [Thales](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/electronic-instrument-system-2-eis2), which ended up with the contracts for all Airbus models.

Comment: @user71659 You should add that as an independent answer (ideally with a short quote from the site you linked).